# How to use of curdate?

Tags: sql-server, date, stored-procedures

I would like to build a stored procedure which can return the value 0 or 1 depending if the day of today is in the list of date.
I did something like this :

```
USE [Alt_db]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_ys]    Script Date: 09/05/2012 14:21:18 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Is_Holyday]
@Value varchar(50),
@Result bit OUTPUT
AS
Begin
If exists (select 1 from Holyday_Date where ISOCNTRYDESC=@Value and Holiday = CURDATE())
set @Result=1
Else
set @Result=0
End
```

But I have an error syntax.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: There is no `CURDATE` in sql-server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server, try:

```
Holiday = getdate()
```

Or for the datepart only:

```
cast(Holiday as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
```

For SQL Server 2005 or older, use:

```
dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, Holiday)) = 
    dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, getdate()))
```

Comment: Using cast(Holiday as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
gives the following error:Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_Is_Holyday, Line 6
Type date is not a defined system type.
Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_Is_Holyday, Line 6
Type date is not a defined system type.

Comment: @francopshenri: Sounds like you're using SQL Server 2005 or older.  I added an old version of the conversion to date.